# find regex expression based character match

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a list of strings something like this:

```
a=['bukt/id=gdhf/year=989/month=98/day=12/hgjhg.csv','bukt/id=76fhfh/year=989/month=08/day=128/hkngjhg.csv']
```

ids are unique.I want to have a output list which will be something like this

```
output_list = ['bukt/id=gdhf/','bukt/id=76fhfh/']
```

So basically need a regex expression to match any id and remove the rest of the part from the string

How can I do that in most efficient way considering the length of the input list is more than 100K

Comment: Are all the strings of the format `bukt/id=xxx/...`?

Comment: @Nick Yes,correct.Only year,month,day value will be changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

rgx = r'(bukt/id=[a-zA-Z0-9]+/).+'
re.search(rgx, string).group(1)
```

The result will be in group 1. This captures "bukt/id=", followed by any alphanumeric characters and then a slash, and throws away the rest.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for regex, you can just `split` your string on `/`, discard everything after the second `/` and then `join` again with `/`:

```
a=['bukt/id=gdhf/year=989/month=98/day=12/hgjhg.csv','bukt/id=76fhfh/year=989/month=08/day=128/hkngjhg.csv']

out = ['/'.join(u.split('/')[:2]) for u in a]
print(out)
```

Output:

```
['bukt/id=gdhf', 'bukt/id=76fhfh']
```

If you want the trailing `/`, just add an empty string to the end of the split array:

```
out = ['/'.join(u.split('/')[:2] + ['']) for u in a]
```

Output:

```
['bukt/id=gdhf/', 'bukt/id=76fhfh/']
```